# How do I test restoring purchases in Xcode Storekit sandbox, if deleting the app clears all transaction data?

Tags: swift, xcode, storekit

The sandbox environment is confusing me in Xcode 14.

I am trying to test the following scenario:

- User makes in-app purchase (non-consumable)
- User deletes app
- User reinstalls app
- User presses Restore Purchases

Once the app is deleted, it clears all of the sandbox transaction data in Debug > Storekit.

So how do I test this scenario, when there's no data to retrieve when I recompile the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `currentEntitlements` property of Transaction everytime a user starts your app to restore their purchases as shown in the code below from the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851204-currententitlements/)

```
func refreshPurchasedProducts() async {
    // Iterate through the user's purchased products.
    for await verificationResult in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
        switch verificationResult {
        case .verified(let transaction):
            // Check the type of product for the transaction
            // and provide access to the content as appropriate.
            ...
        case .unverified(let unverifiedTransaction, let verificationError):
            // Handle unverified transactions based on your
            // business model.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I can't test that if the sandbox data is being wiped by Xcode when deleting and recompiling the app to test it?